# How to create objects inside another class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have this code.

```
#include "Stack.h"

template <class dataType>
class Queue2{

public:
    Queue2(int size);

    bool push(int data);
    bool pop(int &data);

    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();

    bool top(int &data);

    ~Queue2();
};

template <class dataType>
Queue2<dataType>::Queue2(int size = 10) : Stack <dataType> obj1(size), Stack <dataType> obj2(size) {//here i am facing an error. how can i fix it

}
```

I have a templete class **Stack** with constructor like this.

```
Stack(int size=10);
```

Now I want to create two objects of **Stack** class in **Queue2** class.

Comment: What do you mean two objects? Two member variables?

Comment: Push and pop suggests your Queue2 has an internal list. Do you want to to add obj1 and obj2 to it?

Comment: I have to implement Queue with the help of two stack objects. That is why i need two objects as data membrs..

Comment: You should maybe try to learn some basic c++ first. Stackoverflow is not a c++ tutorial.

Comment: It should be ... `:  obj1(size), obj2(size) {}`.

Comment: there seems to be an error - what are you using dataType for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your `Queue2` class two private `Stack` members, you can initialize them in the constructor initialization, and access them individually:

```
class Queue2{
    Stack<dataType> left,right;
public:
    Queue2(int size);
    /* ... */
```

You then define the constructor as:

```
template<typename dataType>
Queue2<dataType>::Queue2(int size = 10)
  : left(size), right(size) {}
```

Comment: can i create two stack objects without inheritance?

Comment: @UsmanKabir What does that even mean?

Comment: according to this code when i creates an object of Queue2 class the size of left object and right object will be default which is 10. 
what i want is 
`Stack <dataType> left(size);`
`Stack <dataType> right(size);`

Comment: Not if you use initialization lists.

Comment: Thanks @Actorclavilis cool